# Order of a simple code

Tags: c#, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Today I have a discussion with my boss about order of my code, but we can't agree about time complexity of my code. I believe that my code is of `O(n)`, but my boss doesn't accept.

What is your idea about order of this code?

```
void Process(Node currentNode)
{
    Print(currentNode.Title); //O(Print)=O(1)
    foreach(Child child in currentNode.Children)
    {
        Process(child);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT1**

Multiple `Node`s doesn't share the same child `Node`. I have a tree.
`Children` is a simple list of `Node` so that its members can easily be visited in liner time.

You can see here the implementation of `Node` class:

```
class Node
{
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public List<Node> Children{get;set}
}
```

Comment: What did your boss say it is?

Comment: May multiple `Node`s share the same child node?

Comment: as long as you're starting at the top of a nested hierarchy and doing a full depth recursion it's O(n), unless there are break conditions present. How can he disagree with this? It's rather obvious. BUT i suppose Child is of type Node, otherwise this wouldnt work.

Comment: @AndreasMüller We don't know anything about `.Children`'s implementation.  For all we know, it may be returning children in some sorted order, in which case `O(N)` has to be at a minimum `Nlog(N)...

Comment: Your boss is right. Remember, your boss is always right by definition.

Comment: @LB2 Sorting won't really matter though when he's just looping through all of them and performing work on it. I am uncertain wether this question contains complete information to properly answer it.

Comment: @AndreasMüller He is not sorting, but implementation of `.Children` may be (or whatever else it is doing to enumerate data - we just don't know).  So that's what I'm trying to say, and agree with your second statement, there is not enough information to actually ascertain time complexity here.  Need `.Children` info to do so.

Comment: @WeylandYutani If you're working somewhere where your boss is unwilling to be told (constructively) when they've made a mistake, then you should really look for another job.  Any good boss would *want* to be told if they had something wrong so that they can fix it.  You just need to be sure to do it politely, and to not call them out on something in an inappropriate context (i.e., in front of others).

Comment: @Merta for all we know it could be IEnumerable<Node> {get {yield return break;}} under which circumstances your boss would ironically be right. You'll have to post more code to get a precise answer on this.

Comment: @AndreasMüller `yield return break` isn't valid.  You meant `yield break`.  Also, if one defines `N` as the number of nodes in the whole tree, then it *is* O(n), but since n is 1, it is *also* O(1).

Comment: If my boss makes a mistake I would quit because boss should never make mistake.

Comment: @timrao:Multiple Nodes doesn't share the same child node. I have a tree.

Comment: @LB2 Children list has some Child objects, and every Child has only and only one string property (Title) and a list of Child called Children.

Comment: @Weyland Yutani, Yes!! You are right!! Remember your advice :D I think that I should accept O(n^2) or even higher(for example o(n^n)!!! ) to save my job :D

Comment: @Andreas Müller if some information needs to answer this question, ask please!
additional information about `Children` added to post.

Comment: @Merta If `.Children` is defined as `List<Child>`, then since `List<T>` is back by an array, enumerating `List<t>` is a linear operation, and is thus `O(N)`.  Since your loop is doing a simple single pass through the enumeration, your overall time-complexity as presented is indeed linear `O(N)`.  (Invite your boss to the post to hear his argument why it is not :) )

Comment: @LB2 as I mentioned in **EDIT1** children is `List<Node>`. I will invite my boss here but if I loss my job know that you are reason of my poverty :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is [a tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29) and `n` is the number of nodes in the tree...

Then yes, it's `O(n)`.

It's fairly easy to see that we only do a constant amount of work per node.

Each node will only be a child to one other node, thus it will only appear in the for-loop once. And since a for-loop iteration, excluding the recursive call, takes `O(1)`, we can see that the for-loop part of the recursion (for all the calls) takes in `O(n)`. And the rest of the function is clearly `O(1)`, and, from the definition of a tree, we can see that we'll only execute the function once per node, thus `O(n)` times.

Thus the total running time is `O(n)`.

**Note:** I'm assuming `Children` is something that can be enumerated in linear time. If this is not true, the running time would be the same as how long it takes to enumerate it. More specifically, the worst-case will be when one node has the remaining `n-1` nodes as children (and none of the other nodes have children). I think the proof of this will distract a bit from the point, so I'll leave that for another day.

---

If it's not a tree, i.e. multiple nodes can have the same children, or there is a cycle, it's not `O(n)`. In the case of a cycle, it wouldn't terminate. If multiple nodes can have the same children, but there isn't a cycle, the running time would be exponential - the root can have `n-1` children. One of those children can have `n-2` children, one of which can have `n-3` children, etc.

Comment: As I mentioned in **EDIT1** `children` is `List<Node>`

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the time order is O(N) where N is the total number of descendants of the element you're `Process`ing. This is because for each descendant, you `Print`. If you do an O(1) task N times, that's O(N).

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how `currentNode.Children` is actually implemented (or what is the underlying backing data structure).

`.Children` can easily be a property that returns its own enumerator with its own implementation, and time complexity would simply depend on the custom enumerator algorithm.

On the surface it does look like it can be `O(N)`, but post definition/implementation behind `.Children` property, and it should be possible to give a more definitive answer.  At this point, there is not enough information to say definitively.

Comment: As I mentioned in **EDIT1** `children` is `List<Node>`